# C++ - Getting Derived type as the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've got a little templating scenario I'm dealing with. Here's the setup for it.

```
class Base {

}

class Derived : Base {

};
```

And my use case:

```
void DoAThing(Base* t) {
     DoAnotherThing(*t);
}

template<typename T>
void DoAnotherThing(T& t) {
}
```

So what I was hoping for was that I would be able to pass a Derived type into my "DoAThing", and then when I pass it through to DoAnotherThing, the template parameter would appear as Derived. I can see that the dereferenced type definitely is resolved by typeid as Derived, but the T type of DoAnotherThing always comes through as Base. Is there any way I can manipulate this so that DoAnotherThing resolves to the derived type that I send?

Edit: Thanks for the answers so far, but it's not quite solved for my use case yet. DoAnotherThing is to actually to create a container of the Derived class, and the problem is that the container type ends up as Container rather than Container. I want DoAThing to continue taking in the Base rather than be templates for the scenarios in which it is called.

Comment: If you need to know the exact type of a polymorphic type it can often mean you're doing it wrong. In any case templates are for compile-time polymorphism, inheritance is for run-time polymorphism, you seem to be confusing the two and might need to explain what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Comment: DoAThing needs to be templated on T as well

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you should make upper casting, if you want from DoAThing method with pointer to the base class call the DoAnotherThing function with pointer to derived class. To achive this you may use 2 options:
1) Use RTTI and get real type, but it requires runtime.
2) Use this method http://arturx64.github.io/programming-world/2015/02/05/lazy-visitor.html to make upper casting without RTTI.